Can a Court Commissioner be sued for for wrongly charging a crime and issuing an arrest warrant?
In Maryland, anyone can press criminal charges against another person (without any involvement of police) simply by going down to the courthouse and filing a written complaint with a judicial official called a "Commissioner".
Once the person files the complaint and swears that it's true, the Commissioner reads it and decides what (if any) crimes to charge. If the Commissioner files criminal charges, he/she also gets to decide weather to issue a court summons or an arrest warrant. If the person is arrested, another Commissioner will decide what their bond (if any) should be.
These commissioners are not lawyers and often have little education and low caliber. However they have a lot of power to disrupt anyone's life with false charges and arrests and pre-trial detention.
If someone is falsely charged/arrested based on incompetence or malice of a commissioner, then what recourse do they have? Is suing for tort likely to succeed? Will the State of Maryland provide a defense lawyer for the commissioner? Any advice on this topic -- even if only tangentially related -- would be appreciated.

If someone else is making a false complaint, they are at fault.

Probably similar to filing a false report to police.

Is there anything in the Court Commissioner job description that says they're expected to investigate the reported crime? If not, how could they be held liable if it's wrong?

Why the downvotes? Honestly....


Can a Court Commissioner be sued for for wrongly charging a crime and
issuing an arrest warrant?

No.
Court Commissioners have absolute immunity from civil liability arising from their official actions. Despite the fact that they are not lawyers, they still count as judges for liability purposes.

So then no recourse for rogue commissioners who are wrongly charging crimes and wrongly ordering arrests?

@SaqibAli The recourse is to defeat the charges at trial or in a pre-trial motion, and to sue anyone who made a misrepresentation to the court to secure an arrest warrant.

In my case 1) charges were dropped before the trial 2) Nobody made misrepresentations to the court, they described truthfully to the commissioner what happened, but then the commissioner filed charges that didn't match the description!!

@SaqibAli So, the charges were dropped and you got your remedy.

What if someone was arrested and spent a night in jail on OBVIOUSLY ludicrous charges that were not based on the facts outlined in the criminal complaint? Is there any recourse for that other than dropped charges?

@SaqibAli There is no other recourse than dropped charges. See, for example, the answer at https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/96122/how-is-compensation-for-defendants-against-whom-charges-are-dismissed-called-and

Thank you. This is the only time I have ever wished I lived in Missouri!
